# NHibernate HasMany with OrderBy override option in Criteria

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

```
  var criteria = MakeCriteriaForFindAllStudents(exportCriteria)
    .AddOrder<Entities.Student>(x => x.LastName, Order.Asc)
                    .AddOrder<Entities.Student>(x => x.FirstName, Order.Asc);


    criteria.SetFetchMode("Addresses", FetchMode.Join)
                        .SetFetchMode("CR", FetchMode.Join)
                        .SetFetchMode("SEC", FetchMode.Join)
                        .SetFetchMode("Dep", FetchMode.Join)
                        .SetFetchMode("WR", FetchMode.Join)
                        .SetResultTransformer(new DistinctRootEntityResultTransformer());

    var results = criteria
                    .GetExecutableCriteria(Session)
                    .Future<Entities.Student>();
```

The AddOrder seems not to work in certain conditions.

The Student fluent mapping has the following relation to WR.

```
HasMany(x => x.WR)
                .Table("WR")
                .KeyColumn("StudentId")
                .LazyLoad()
                .AsSet()
                .Inverse()
                .Cascade.None()
                .OrderBy("CreatedDate desc")
                .BatchSize(10);
```

So when SetFetchMode on WR is called, the OrderBy part of the mapping supercedes the AddOrder specified in the code.

sample of the sql code..

```
ORDER BY wr6_.CreatedDate desc, this_.LNametxt asc, this_.FNameTxt asc;
```

How to override the mapping defined and ensure that WR CreatedDate is removed from OrderBy is removed from Criteria ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it is know bug in NHibernate, here is the link

http://www.primordialcode.com/blog/post/nhibernate-eager-fetch-order-strange-behavior-icriteria

Answer (score 1):

take a look at the generated sql. Maybe the order is included somewhere in the query (i.e. in a subquery) and does just not have any effect on the result set. Depends on how MakeCriteriaForFindAllStudents() builds the ICriteria.

Comment: looking at the sql gen helped me.